# compiling xmlrpc.net with Strong-Name Signing , when adding to my dll resource still gives :"does not have a strong name"

Tags: c#, strongname

i have dll im creating in c# using visual studio 2008 pro. i need to use in this dll the xmlrpc.net dll. in xmlrpc.net i recompile the dll with [Private Key Pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy.aspx)
then i used this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b.aspx) to set it up in the xmlrpc.net.

in my dll i added a resource and pointed to the xmlrpc dll. but when i compile my dll im still getting the error :

> error CS1577: Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'CookComputing.XmlRpcV2' does not have a strong name

what im doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

my dll is also bean signed with a key, they both using different keys.

**UPDATE 2, SOLVED:**

I needed to add `<SignAssembly> true </SignAssembly>`:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectType>Local</ProjectType>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{1B4B0A58-0AFB-4090-91DD-18912CC7DE65}</ProjectGuid>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ApplicationIcon>
    </ApplicationIcon>
    <AssemblyKeyContainerName>
    </AssemblyKeyContainerName>
    <AssemblyName>CookComputing.XmlRpcV2</AssemblyName>
    <SignAssembly> true </SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == ''">xmlrpc_strongname.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DefaultClientScript>JScript</DefaultClientScript>
    <DefaultHTMLPageLayout>Grid</DefaultHTMLPageLayout>
    <DefaultTargetSchema>IE50</DefaultTargetSchema>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>xmlrpc</RootNamespace>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
    <StartupObject>
    </StartupObject>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <SignAssembly Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == ''">true</SignAssembly>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>..\bin\</OutputPath>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <BaseAddress>285212672</BaseAddress>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>false</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <ConfigurationOverrideFile>
    </ConfigurationOverrideFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <FileAlignment>4096</FileAlignment>
    <NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>
    <NoWarn>649</NoWarn>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <RemoveIntegerChecks>false</RemoveIntegerChecks>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>..\bin\</OutputPath>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <BaseAddress>285212672</BaseAddress>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>false</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <ConfigurationOverrideFile>
    </ConfigurationOverrideFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <FileAlignment>4096</FileAlignment>
    <NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>
    <NoWarn>649</NoWarn>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <RemoveIntegerChecks>false</RemoveIntegerChecks>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <Name>System</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data">
      <Name>System.Data</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing">
      <Name>System.Drawing</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web">
      <Name>System.Web</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms">
      <Name>System.Windows.Forms</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml">
      <Name>System.XML</Name>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DateTime8601.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GuidEx.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IHttpRequest.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IHttpRequestHandler.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IHttpResponse.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IXmlRpcProxy.cs" />
    <Compile Include="RequestResponseLogger.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SystemMethodsBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Tracer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="util.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcAsyncResult.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcBeginAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcBoolean.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcClientFormatterSink.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcClientFormatterSinkProvider.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcClientProtocol.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcDateTime.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcDocWriter.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcDouble.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcEndAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcException.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcFaultException.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcHttpRequest.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcHttpResponse.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcHttpServerProtocol.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcInt.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcListenerRequest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcListenerResponse.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcListenerService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcLogger.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcMemberAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcMethodAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcMethodInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcMissingMappingAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcNonStandard.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcParameterAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcParameterInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcProxyCodeGen.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcProxyGen.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcRequest.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcRequestEventArgs.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcResponse.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcResponseEventArgs.cs" />
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcReturnValueAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcSerializer.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcServerFormatterSink.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcServerProtocol.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcService.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcServiceAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcServiceInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcStruct.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="XmlRpcUrlAttribute.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="xmlrpc_strongname.snk" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
    </PreBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="AssemblyBuildNumber.cs" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == ''">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Compile" />
    </CreateItem>
    <CreateItem Include="AssemblyDescFX1_0.cs" Condition="'$(TargetFX1_0)'=='true'">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Compile" />
    </CreateItem>
    <CreateItem Include="AssemblyDesc.cs" Condition="'$(TargetFX1_0)'!='true'">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Compile" />
    </CreateItem>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: There are not a lot of ways this could go wrong.  Sounds to me you are referencing the original CookComputing.XmlRpc2.dll instead of the re-compiled one.  Or you use the msbuild script to build it instead of `src\xmlrpc.sln`

Comment: no , im using the visual studio 2008 IDE , no scripts .
also i know that im using the recompiled dll , coz when i clean the xmlrpc dll , im my dll i see it missing

Comment: Okay, I repro.  The xmlrpc.csproj file is pretty broken, it contains both a Debug and a Debug|AnyCPU configuration.  It confuses the stuffing out of msbuild, it builds the wrong one.  You'll have to edit this file with a text editor like Notepad.  Use the .csproj file of a sample class library project to get it right.

Comment: thanks for your time answering , where do i need to fix/add/remove in the file i updated my question . can you please show me ?